# EF 6 Rollback and Update Best Approach

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have a working solution in place and i m initiating this thread to have a discussion on the best approach.

Environment : EF6, SQL 2012
Scenario:

I have Task and TaskDetail table which have parent child/relationship through TaskID.

**Create Method:**
While creating a task, i need to ensure an entry is made in TaskDetail table as well. 
**First approach:**
An entry is made into Task Table. SaveChanges. Get the TaskID and assign into the DTO which has the information for Detail table. Pass the DTO to the TaskDetail create Method. Save changes. Commit.. If any error occurs, rollback entire transaction

**Second Approach:**
Add relavent fields of Task table. Add relevant fields of Task Detail table as well. Add the new detail table object to Task table through the navigation property. Task.Taskdetail.Add(newObj). Finally SaveChanges.

**Question 1:**
Both the approaches yield same SQL. Couldnt notice much difference though.. But what would be the best approach for doing this???

**Question 2:**
Also, if you take a look at my scenario, you would have noticed that its SaveAll or SaveNone approach. Initially i tried with looping through DbEntityEntries and then rollbacked the change. But that sounds working for Second approach described above and not for the first approach since i m making a save after my insertion in order to get the TaskID. Then finally i ended up with using "DbConextTransaction" introduced in EF 6. But what is the best approach???

**Question 3:**

**Update Method:**

While doing an update , as per my requirement, i will not touch the Task table. It deals with TaskDetail table alone though the task ID would be required which will be passed from the UI.

- •    Get the existing task detail using the task ID and active flag
  (There is one to many relationship)
- Update the active flag as false
- Create new entry in Task Detail table

I just translated the above statements into code implementation as well but what would be the best approach to handle it????

Comment: Entity Framework will handle a lot of that automatically: giving child the parent id (your second approach), wrapping it in a transaction (unit of work). Just make sure you only have a single SaveChanges() and it's all or none out of the box. Unless I'm not understanding your issue.